# Raspberry Pi won't send data through serial port

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python, serial

I have simple app in python that should send data through serial port (serial0/ttyS0):

```
import RPi.GPIO as io
import time
import serial
import array

io.setmode(io.BCM)

ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/serial0",
                        baudrate=38400,
                        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                        xonxoff=False,
                        rtscts=False,
                        timeout=1)

text = "200\r\n"
ser.write(bytes(text.encode('ascii')))
```

And this app won't to send me data through serial port. How can I check if it really send anything? Maybe I can measure voltage on GPIO pin?

Comment: what's connected to the other end of the serial port? perhaps you have rx and tx connected incorrectly?

Comment: To the serial port IR sensor are connected. RXD works, I get data when IR receive signal, but I cannot send signal from the second IR sensor that is connected to TXD

Comment: so, TXD is connected to an IR *emitter* I hope (a sensor won't emit IR, it resieves it) - do you know how to check if anything is being sent via the IR emitter? if you have a mobile phone with a camera, watch the sensor through the camera when sending

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've checked IR emitter and it emitted only one time. I've checked as you wrote - by using camera from phone. Then when I run application several times after this first time the senser (IR emitter) doesn't emit signal (I don't see nothing in camera). I restarted RPi but without result

Comment: It works, problem was with text, it shoudn't contains \n at the end, probably python add eof by default. I removed \n and now it works